# How do i detect If I started scrolling from outside the div and entered the div or I am scrolling inside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollview, mousewheel

Issue right now: https://www.loom.com/share/c2567ccbd8e44ab49d1138e65ae77973

I have a section or div in the middle of the page. On every scroll, I need to detect if I entered that div after scrolling from outside that div (either up scroll or down scroll) or I am just scrolling inside that div?

I will explain what I am trying to achieve

This is the site https://dev.plusplus.co/events/
For this section https://prnt.sc/25nbxzq

What I am trying to achieve is when I start scrolling from the top of the page, and after I enter that above section, the section locks and there is a slick slider inside that div and after the section locks, I need to change slides on up and down scroll.

But What is happening right now is especially in firefox browser, If I scroll from the top and enter that div, the slider automatically changes to second. I need to lock the scroll first which works and when I enter that section and scroll and then only change slide to second on next scroll

Code I am using right now.

```
// debounce from underscore.js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

// use x and y mousewheel event data to navigate flickity
function slick_handle_wheel_event(e, slick_instance, slick_is_animating) {
  // do not trigger a slide change if another is being animated
  if (!slick_is_animating) {
    // pick the larger of the two delta magnitudes (x or y) to determine nav direction
    var direction =
      Math.abs(e.deltaX) > Math.abs(e.deltaY) ? e.deltaX : e.deltaY;

    console.log("wheel scroll ", e.deltaX, e.deltaY, direction);

    if (direction > 0) {
      // next slide
      slick_instance.slick("slickNext");
    } else {
      // prev slide
      slick_instance.slick("slickPrev");
    }
  }
}

// debounce the wheel event handling since trackpads can have a lot of inertia
var slick_handle_wheel_event_debounced = debounce( 
  slick_handle_wheel_event
  , 80, true
);




// slider #2
const slick_3 = $("#firstscrollsection .content-left");
slick_3.not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        dots: false,
          vertical: true,
    speed: 400,
    fade: true,
    waitForAnimate: false,
    verticalSwiping: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: false,
      
          infinite: false,
});
var slick_3_is_animating = false;

slick_3.on("afterChange", function(index) {
  console.log("Slide after change " + index);
  slick_3_is_animating = false;
});

slick_3.on("beforeChange", function(index) {
  console.log("Slide before change " + index);
  slick_3_is_animating = true;
});




  $("#firstscrollsection .section-wrapper-animated").on("wheel", function(e) {



      slick_handle_wheel_event_debounced(e.originalEvent, slick_3, slick_3_is_animating); 


  });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what's the goal? There's the example of a menu/nav-bar when you scroll down enough it sticks to top. Few examples but what you asked for it's really not specific I would revise question.

Comment: Could you provide some more clarity? I'm unable to interpret the post from reading the heading. What do you mean by _"I need to detect if I entered that div"_? Can you add a sketch or visual representation of what you are trying to create?

Comment: Issues explained in more detail @Vektor

Comment: Issues explained in more detail @BGPHiJACK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to create a parallax effect, I believe you're going about it the wrong way.

I'm also curious about these lines of code:

```js
// pick the larger of the two delta magnitudes (x or y) to determine nav direction
var direction = Math.abs(e.deltaX) > Math.abs(e.deltaY) ? e.deltaX : e.deltaY;
console.log("wheel scroll ", e.deltaX, e.deltaY, direction);
```

Is there a reason for comparing `deltaY` with `deltaX`? As I understand that you're calculating scroll direction on the vertical axis.

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) outlines the following — maybe this could be the source of the issue with Firefox:

> **Note:** Don't confuse the `wheel` event with the `scroll` event. The default action of a `wheel` event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a `scroll` event. Even when it does, the `delta*` values in the `wheel` event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction. Therefore, do not rely on the `wheel` event's `delta*` properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect value changes of `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` of the target in the `scroll` event.

If the pointer isn't directly hovering over the section, its `wheel` event won't fire. Also, the `wheel` event won't consider touch or scrollbar events. It's a better idea, in my opinion, to instead listen for the `scroll` event on the `documentElement`.

Here is my suggestion for changing the slide on the next scroll. You can detect if the `scrollTop` of the document meets your target element's(section in this case) `offsetTop`, then you will start calculating scroll direction before navigating the slider.

Comment: Your suggestion cannot work, because his element is a slider with a hidden overflow. So he's "scrolling" the slides inside that element programmatically, by detecting wheel (that is hardware) changes in the delta property. So using the scroll event and its properties cannot work here because those work only with overflow that is scrollable using the browser's native scrollbars (ie, overflow is not specifically hidden).